# How to build ffmpeg as a Position independent executable (PIE) or PIC?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have checked out the latest source of ffmpeg from the official website. I now want to compile and build  ffmpeg as a position independent executable.

Here is what my configure command looks like

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-pic --enable-nonfree --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265
```

I have added the option `--enable-pic` to make it a PIE. However when the build process completes successfully and when I do a hardening check as follows then I get below output

hardening-check ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg:
Position Independent Executable: no, normal executable!
Stack protected: yes
Fortify Source functions: yes (some protected functions found)
Read-only relocations: yes
Immediate binding: no, not found!
```

This tells me that ffmpeg is still not a PIE. Can anyone tell me what am I missing here? Is there any other changes that need to be done for adding PIE support.

**UPDATE:**

Platform : Ubuntu (15.04) Linux 64 bit

I need to compile ffmpeg for Android with PIE support.

Comment: ok my mistake. It's Position independent executable. then how to build ffmpeg with PIE support ?

Comment: Quoting from the advanced linking configuration of the Ffmpeg docs: If you compiled FFmpeg libraries statically and you want to use them to build your own shared library, you may need to force PIC support (with --enable-pic during FFmpeg configure) and add the following option to your project LDFLAGS:

-Wl,-Bsymbolic 

If your target platform requires position independent binaries, you should pass the correct linking flag (e.g.-pie) to --extra-ldexeflags.

Comment: I downvoted your question for not even mentioning the platform your on. Unfortunately people here are not psychic and can read your thoughts.

Comment: @HansMeiser: As you can see i have enabled --enable-pic in my command also but where should I set LDFLAGS option. Is it in the configure file present inside the ffmpeg source?

Comment: Does this help? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1471616

Comment: @HansMeiser: Yes it does help. Over there it is mentioned that there is no need to add any --extra-cflags. only --enable-shared automatically implies --enable-pic on x86_64. So that means i just need to add --enable-shared in my present command and it should work right?

Comment: Try it... Just take care to do the "sudo ldconfig" part as well.